# Variable value can only be changed through xdebug, not php code

Tags: php, xdebug

I have come across a strange issue where in writing some PHP code. If I change the value of a previously assigned variable in code, that value does not persists to another part of my application. If I set a breakpoint and then change the value through my debugger however, the value persists to the later part.

Even stranger is that if I change it in code and after I set a breakpoint, when I then change the value it doesn’t get through to the later part of my code.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening here?

Variable is part of an array passed into the function by reference, if I add an element to another array contained within the parent array this persists.

This issue has presented itself a couple of times now.

PHP Version 5.4.36-0+deb7u3
Xdebug Version 2.2.1

Below is requested code example, from Drupal so may be a little difficult to get into but when the breakpoint kicks in I can see the variable I want to change has the correct value set. This however has been lost by the time the variable is used again. If I remove the line that sets the new value (for title) and instead change it in my debugger, this works fine.

```
function eh_link_block_preprocess_entity(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['entity_type'] == 'eh_link_block') {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('eh_link_block', $variables['eh_link_block']);

    $wrapper->field_link->title->set('New Title');

    xdebug_break();    
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal example of this behaviour?

Comment: check  variable name spelling ....

Comment: Code example added, hope this is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OPCache by any chance? check php.ini or phpinfo() output for "opcache" string, if it is used, it caches the files for some time.

APC Cache could cache files as well, try to run this code and then run the script in question (Better way is to disable APC in php.ini, then restart the web server, and then test the script)

```
apc_clear_cache();
apc_clear_cache('user');
apc_clear_cache('opcode');
```

Comment: Not opcache no... You could be onto something though. Would memcached or APC do something like that?

Comment: That doesn't appear to have solved it.... I've removed both APC & Memcached. Thanks though, really though that was gonna be it!